# Is there a common parent class between TIntHashSet and Set in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I was trying to create an abstract class that could use either Set or a TIntHashSet. I wanted to have it use the .contains or .addAll that both classes implement but unfortunately I can't find a common parent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this using inheritance as there is no common ancestor.

The best way to do this is to use the strategy pattern. Your abstract class contains:

```
SetInterfaceStrategy setInterface;
```

setInterface stores the Set or TIntHashSet internally and exposes the methods you want to use. Set the correct strategy inside your abstract object for the type of set it is accessing.

This is very similar to the suggestion of using the `TIntSetDecorator` but allows you more control, so you can try and avoid the boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use [`TIntSetDecorator`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/decorator/TIntSetDecorator.html) to view a `TIntHashSet` as a `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: But if you do that you lose most of the advantages of using `TIntHashSet` - you'll be boxing and unboxing, which `TIntHashSet` was designed for to avoid.

Comment: Correct.  There's no way around that if you want to use a common interface.